# What does "CA" stand for on a lead acid rechargable battery data sheet

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

I am trying to use the following NP2-12FR Yuasa lead acid battery for a portable speaker project. I'm looking at the [datasheet](https://www.yuasabatteries.com.au/YuasaBatteriesNZ/media/Battery_Misc/YU109-1646-YuasaNP-Product-Spec-NP2-12FR.pdf) and I am a bit bamboozled by these two graphs. What do the different lines, with different values of "CA" mean. What does "CA" stand for?

[image]
[image]

Comment: 3CA = 3C Amps. C is the rate at which it will nominally charge or discharge in 1 hour. (In practice as the first chart shows, discharging at 1C will only give you about 30 minutes not 60; but note the capacity is specified at 0.05C, aka tho 20 hour rate.

Comment: Cranking Amps, maybe?

Answer (score 4):

CA is battery capacity in ampere-hours, in your case 2.  In the right-most curve at the top, the battery is subjected to a constant current load of 0.05CA (0.05 * 2) or 0.1 amps.  The battery provides 0.1 amps for 20 hours, giving the 2 ampere-hour rating.  The curve marked "0.6CA" would have the battery subjected to a constant current load of 0.6 * 2 or 1.2 amps, and the battery provides this current for about one hour, so at this rate the battery provides 1.2 ampere-hours (the data sheet table says 1.25).

This type of chart can then be applied to others of the same family of batteries with different capacities.